# PS to list specific directories that contain files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to write a PS script that will search for all directories labelled Restricted Data and return a result if there are any files in the Restricted Data folder or its subfolders. The problem that I'm having is that it will return a result even when there are empty subfolders inside Restricted Data.  I thought it might be because my script contains `$_.GetDirectories().Count -gt 0` but don't get any results valid or not when I remove that part.

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like "Restricted Data" -and ($_.GetFiles().Count -gt 0 -or $_.GetDirectories().Count -gt 0)}`

Any ideas?

I'm updating this post to include some of the particulars that are being asked.

The file structure is like the example below.  Each RootFolder will contain one or more PName folders.  Each PName folder may contain a single folder named Restricted Data.  Each Restricted Data folder will contain subfolders.  These subfolders may or may not contain files and there may be files located directly inside the Restricted Data folder itself.  If the script finds any files either directly in the Restricted Data folder or in any of the subfolders I need it to return a result indicating the RootFolder\PName path for these directories.

RootFolder1\PName\Restricted Data\Subfolder\Subfolder\file.docx
RootFolder1\PName2\Restricted Data\Subfolder\Subfolder\file.docx
RootFolder2\PName\Restricted Data\Subfolder\Subfolder
RootFolder3\PName\Restricted Data\Subfolder\file.xlsx

RootFolder4\PName\Restricted Data\Subfolder\

Comment: You need to refine your question to give us an idea of what a directory structure might look like and what output you require. For instance if the program finds a directory with "Restricted Data" in the title should we continue to look for nested "Restricted Data" directories? Is it find it once on a tree then report if there are any directories below containing files? See where I'm going here?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, here is a directory structure with some sample files.  All are directories except the two `test.txt` files in the following structure:

```
C:\TEMP\test
C:\TEMP\test2
C:\TEMP\test3
C:\TEMP\test2\Restricted Data
C:\TEMP\test2\test.txt
C:\TEMP\test2\Restricted Data\test.txt
C:\TEMP\test3\Restricted Data
C:\TEMP\test3\Restricted Data\empty
```

This command will only find the directories with the exact name `Restricted Data` and then only list those `Restricted Data` directories with more than one file:

```
dir -Recurse -Directory -Path 'Restricted Data' | ?{ (Get-ChildItem $_ -File).Count } | %{ "$($_.FullName): $((Get-ChildItem $_ -File).Count)" }
```

or with aliases removed:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path 'Restricted Data' | `
    Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem $_ -File).Count } | `
    Foreach-Object { "$($_.FullName): $((Get-ChildItem $_ -File).Count)" }
```

You can change the output, but my example just shows the number files when `Restricted Data` isn't empty:

```
C:\TEMP\test2\Restricted Data: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script.

It only lists directories matching the search term and which contain at least one file.
It does not count files.

Furthermore it saves processing time since it does not enumerate all files when one has been already found in that particular folder (done by using System.Linq)

```powershell
$rootDirectoryPath = 'C:\Temp'
$searchTerm        = 'Restricted Data'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootDirectoryPath -Directory -Filter $searchTerm -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { 
        ($null -ne [System.Linq.Enumerable]::FirstOrDefault(
                [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($_.FullName, '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
            )
        ) 
    }
```

### Update

This one is a much simpler solution and maybe better when it comes to access exceptions.

When using Direcotry.EnumerateFiles (from previous solution) and it encounters a "Access denied" exception, it will stop and doesn't look into other directories.

The new solution will not stop. It just throws an exception and uses the next directory.

```powershell
$rootDirectoryPath = 'C:\Temp'
$searchTerm        = 'Restricted Data'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootDirectoryPath -Directory -Filter $searchTerm -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { 
        $null -ne (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1)
    }
```

Comment: Pwnosh...thanks for this solution!  It runs well and is very clean.  I like how it returns just the base directory for each result instead of the path to each and every file in Restricted Data.  There are sometimes 100's of files in these directories.  One thing I discovered is that buried in every Restricted Data directory is a single README.TXT file. And so, unfortunately, it returns a false positive.  Is there anyway to exclude that single file from the search?

Comment: Just add `-Exclude 'readme.txt'` as parameter to the second `Get-ChildItem` command.

Comment: Will do.  Thank you!